# combining outputs from functions

Tags: python, list

I have created a binary "table" in the form of a list using this code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

x = [i for i in product(range(2), repeat = 9)]
x = np.array(x)
```

from there I create 3 functions that calculate a probability I want:

```
def FPP1(x):
    fh_prob = 0.002
    trust = 0
    for item in x:
        if item[0] > 0:
            trust = fh_prob
            print(trust)
        if item[0] == 0:
            trust = 1 - fh_prob
            print(trust)

def FPP2(x):
    fh_prob = 0.002
    trust = 0
    for item in x:
        if item[1] == 1:
            trust = fh_prob
            print(trust)
        if item[1] == 0:
            trust = 1 - fh_prob
            print(trust)

def FPP3(x):
    fh_prob = 0.002
    trust = 0
    for item in x:
        if item[2] == 1:
            trust = fh_prob
            print(trust)
        if item[2] == 0:
            trust = 1 - fh_prob
            print(trust)
```

There are about 512 outputs for each function, I would love to store them in one list or table. Something along the lines of column A is FPP1, column B is FPP2, and column 3 is FPP3. I do not know how to accomplish this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your functions don't return anything

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html maybe try this?

Comment: Change the functions to return a list of results instead of printing them. Then you can add each one as a column to your array.

Comment: I think this question is a great example of the [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). why not just use `np.where` to check the if conditions and return the fph_prob value in a vectorized manner. No need for iterations or stacking or pandas conversions etc. Utilize numpy with all its benefits! Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *printing* the value you need in the functions, create a list and *return* them. For example, for `FPP1`:

```
def FPP1(x):
    fh_prob = 0.002
    trust = 0
    output = [trust] #list that the function will return
    for item in x:
        if item[0] > 0:
            trust = fh_prob
            output.append(trust) #append to the list instead of printing
        if item[0] == 0:
            trust = 1 - fh_prob
            output.append(trust)
    return output #return list of values
```

After similar modifications to `FPP2` and `FPP3`, you can create a 2d list of all outputs with:

```
output = [FPP1(x), FPP2(x), FPP3(x)]
```

If you want a `pandas.DataFrame` instead, you can do:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([FPP1(x), FPP2(x), FPP3(x)]).transpose()
>>> output
         0      1      2
0    0.000  0.000  0.000
1    0.998  0.998  0.998
2    0.998  0.998  0.998
3    0.998  0.998  0.998
4    0.998  0.998  0.998
..     ...    ...    ...
508  0.002  0.002  0.002
509  0.002  0.002  0.002
510  0.002  0.002  0.002
511  0.002  0.002  0.002
512  0.002  0.002  0.002

[513 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Pandas seems to be an overkill, why not use `np.hstack` or `np.vstack` simply. that way no need for any data conversion.

Comment: OP asked for "one list or table" so I included solutions for one 2d list and one DataFrame (table).

Answer (score 1):

#### I think this question is a great example of the [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

**Problem:** You are trying to apply a conditional check on each of columns of a matrix and return custom values for each column.

**Attempted Solution:** You create 9 functions (3 in this case) and apply on complete data using only 1 column for each. Then stack them.

**Better solution:** Just apply the same check on the complete matrix but return different values for each column!

---

When working with NumPy, why not try to vectorize your functions? You don't need to work with FOR loops and if-conditions for most cases.

> Looking at the 3 functions you built, which work on 1 of the 9 columns (each one separate), I am assuming you will end up building 9 such functions and apply 1 to each column.

Just vectorize the functions in 2 lines of code as this -

1. Create a list of 9 values of `fh_prob`
2. Use `np.where` to check if `x>0`. If it is, then return the corresponding column's`fh_prob` else return `1-fh_prob`
3. Take the relevant columns that you need (in this case the first 3)

```
#Define the fh_prob for each of the 9 columns
fh_prob = np.array([0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002]) ## (9,) 


#check condition on value for x and return corresponding column's fh_prob or 1-fh_prob
thrust = np.where(x>0, fh_prob, 1-fh_prob)

#pick up the columns you need
thrust[:,:3]
```

```
array([[0.998, 0.997, 0.996],
       [0.998, 0.997, 0.996],
       [0.998, 0.997, 0.996],
       ...,
       [0.002, 0.003, 0.004],
       [0.002, 0.003, 0.004],
       [0.002, 0.003, 0.004]])
```

So much simpler than writing 9 functions and then stacking them using numpy or pandas right?